# Does Unicode search work?

Tags: drupal, search, unicode

- Drupal 6.2 search has been enabled, permissions given, and [re-indexed](http://pssnet.com/~devone/drupaltest/).
- The search picks up certain strings (இன்றைய காலகட்டத்தில்) while not others (மேற்குறித்த கட்டுரைக்கு).
- Database is UTF-8 Unicode encoded, the web pages are displaying correctly.
- There seems to be several known issues, but no one has posted a clear solution for this issue at the Drupal [website](http://drupal.org/node/604002). I tried to apply some of the suggested patches, and they failed.

Comment: Did the patches fail? Or did they fail to apply cleanly?

Comment: The patches failed to apply cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Are the words getting indexed? IOW, are they showing up in the search_index table?

Comment: Check the search_index table.

Comment: It is definitely not indexing full words as in English.

Comment: Tamil Words are broken into three letter meaningless phases.  It may have worked if the breakup was for full characters.  But the collation screws up them upto be meaningless.